# select subset of different data.frame columns

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I want to select a different a subset of a dataframe from each column and do and average like this

```
per <- data.frame(Apocal=c(10,1,2,3,4,0,6),Aporos=c(0,2,1,3,0,5,6),Euker=c(0,3,5,7,0,0,0), fecha=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3))

temp <-with(per, per[Apocal>0,])
require(plyr)
temp <- ddply(temp, .(fecha), summarise, Apocal = mean(Apocal))

temp <-with(per, per[Aporos>0,])
temp <- ddply(temp, .(fecha), summarise, Aporos = mean(Aporos))

...
```

And repeat for every column, except fecha, is there any way to automate this with a function or another thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(. ~ fecha, data = per, function(x)mean(x[x > 0]))
#   fecha Apocal Aporos Euker
# 1     1    5.5    2.0     3
# 2     2    3.0    2.0     6
# 3     3    6.0    5.5   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

If your function is `mean` you can use the function `colMeans` normally. It computes mean of all columns (column-wise means). But since you require to compute the mean *after* removing each column's 0 entries, you can use `colSums` as follows:

```
# x gets all columns grouped by `fecha`.
ddply(per, .(fecha), function(x) colSums(x[, -4])/colSums(x[, -4] != 0))
#   fecha Apocal Aporos Euker
# 1     1    5.5    2.0     3
# 2     2    3.0    2.0     6
# 3     3    6.0    5.5   NaN
```

Comment: you forgot the OP wants to filter out `0` before taking means.

Comment: @flodel, yes I suspected I've gotten something wrong. Thanks for pointing it out. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

```
pmean <- function(x,byvar){
  y=x[,-1*byvar]
  colSums(y*(y>0))/colSums(y>0)
}

ddply(per, .(fecha), function(x) pmean(x,4))
```

Modified version of Arun's soluton.

Comment: `colSums(y)/colSums(y>0)` is sufficient, no? Adding `y = 0` entries will not affect the sum of numerator.

Comment: @Arun what if, when some y are negative? say `y=c(-1,0,1)`

Comment: I don't know why, but I assumed that the `>` is not the intended operator, rather it's `!=`. If there could be negative values, this is a bad example from the OP and your answer is much nicer to have covered it! I'll delete my post soon.